# C nested for loops add empty line after each 10 iterations

Tags: c, nested-loops

I want to print all combinations of length 2 from an array of characters (like aa, ab, ..., az, ba, bb, ...., etc). Can somebody explain to me why this code incorrect:

```
int main(void){
   char a[]="abcdefghijk";
   for (int i=0; i<11; i++){
       for (int j=0; j<11 && a[j]!='\n'; j++){
           char r[2] = {a[i], a[j]};
           printf("I-th element: %c     ", a[i]);
           printf("J-th element: %c     ", a[j]);
           printf("Together: %s", r);
           printf("\n");
       }
   }
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that after every eleventh combination empty line is printed. If an array is shorter than 10 everything seemed to be fine.

Output looks like this:
[screenshot of my IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jfbQ.png)

Comment: `char r[2] = {a[i], a[j]};` --> `char r[3] = {a[i], a[j]};`

Comment: Note: `a[j]!='\n'` is alwasy true in this case.

Comment: As [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021116/c-nested-for-loops-add-empty-line-after-each-10-iterations#comment77016627_45021116) commented or `printf("Together: %.2s", r);`

Comment: Avoid *magic numbers*, e.g. `for (int j=0; j<sizeof a - 1; j++)`

Comment: Well, you don't really need `r`, you can use `printf("Together: %c%c\n", a[i], a[j]);`

Comment: You do need `r` if you want to treat the combined elements as a *string*, but you are correct, you could provide 2 char *format specifiers* instead.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - right you are -- fixed `:)`

Comment: this expression: `&& a[j]!='\n'` will never be false so can be eliminated.

Comment: this line: `printf("Together: %s", r);` is undefined behavior because the array `r[2]` is NOT a NUL terminated character array. Suggest: `printf( "Together: %c%c", r[0], r[1] );`

Answer (score 0):

here is a version of the posted code, that does not have any undefined behavior, so the output is as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf()

int main(void)
{
   char a[]="abcdefghijk";

   for (int i=0; i<11; i++)
   {
       for (int j=0; j<11; j++)
       {
           printf("I-th element: %c     ", a[i]);
           printf("J-th element: %c     ", a[j]);
           printf("Together: %c%c", a[i], a[j]);
           printf("\n");
       }
   }
  return 0;
}
```